# Getting the parent path from a script

Tags: shell, process

I have a bash script `foocaller`, which calls a ruby script `foo`:

**foocaller**

```
/path/to/foo
```

Within `foo`, I want to get the path of `foocaller`. Following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230310/calling-ruby-from-shell/24230553#24230553), I put the following code to do that:

**foo**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts File.read("/proc/#{Process.ppid}/cmdline")
```

When I run:

```
$ bash foocaller
```

then I get the desired:

```
bash^@/path/to/foocaller
```

but when I directly call `foocaller`:

```
$ foocaller
```

then I get this:

```
/bin/bash^@--noediting^@-i
```

which does not show the path to `foocaller`. How can I get the path to `foocaller` by directly calling `foocaller` without `bash`?

Comment: What is your OS and ruby version? I use Fedora and it works fine.

Comment: @Gnouc OS is Ubuntu. Ruby version is irrelevant.

Comment: Add a `exit` at the end your foocaller script, otherwise, foocaller may execute foo in the same process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many shells optimise the last command in a script by executing the command in the same process:

```
$ sh -c 'ps
ps'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
32673 pts/3    00:00:00 zsh
32696 pts/3    00:00:00 sh
32697 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
32673 pts/3    00:00:00 zsh
32696 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

See how the second `ps` was executed in the process that initially ran `sh` (32696), and then its parent is the `sh`'s parent (in my case here, `zsh` my interactive shell).

You can avoid that by adding an `exit` line:

```
#! /bin/sh -
foo
exit
```

`sh` cannot execute `foo` in the same process because, it still has more to interpret after `foo` has finished. So it will instead run `foo` in another process and wait for it. And then run `exit` (which will exit the script with the same exit status as that of `foo`).

Now, that's not very optimal, as you could have saved a process here.

A better way to have `foo` know about the path of `foocaller` could be to tell it:

```
#! /bin/sh -
CALLER=$0 foo
```

Then `foo` can query the `CALLER` environment variable to get the path of its caller (`import os;print(os.environ["CALLER"])` in python)